# Random Post on 404 url nginx

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, wordpress

I'm having a funny issue on my Wordpress lemp instalation. Here's the thing:

Lets suppose you have a url of  `example.com/category-of-shoes` which leads to a post regarding such matter. When I type a non-existing post/page for example `example.com/category`instead of getting a 404 response I get bounced to `example.com/category-of-shoes`.

What could be the problem here? This is happening on some sites I maintain and I'm afraid that someone might be able to exploit this. Also is this related to cgi.fix_pathinfo?

---

My Conf file for the server:

```
upstream php {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
server {
    listen 80;

    set $host_path "/var/www/vhosts/example.com/";
    access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/example.com-error.log error;


    server_name  example.com;
    root   $host_path;

    charset utf-8;
    index  index.php;

    location ~ \.php {
           fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
           fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
           include fastcgi_params;
           fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
           fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
           fastcgi_param  PATH_TRANSLATED  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
   }

   location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
            index  index.php;
   }
   location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
            expires max;
            log_not_found off;
   }


    error_page   404             /404.html;
    error_page   500 502 503 504 /static.html;
}
```

Also I'm a bit confused about all the options people seem to give for the WP Permalink "rewrite" on nginx. most of what i see revolves around:               `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;` inside the `location /` block. Can someone explain me this issue pleas?

Comment: Not an nginx issue. WordPress does a search if there isn't an exact match to the URL and that is the closest match. If you delete or rename the page /category-of-shoes you should start seeing your 404 page.

Comment: then how come it doesn't happen on apache as well? I have a couple of websites running on apache and with the same versions and this issue doesn't happen on apache.